# need to return empty string instead of 0

Tags: sql

I have to return an empty string in my case statement, but for some reason I am getting 0. The TagID datatype is Tinyint

```
SELECT TagID, CASE WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(TagID))>10 THEN '' ELSE TagID END
FROM [dbo].tblUse
```

This is the result I am getting

```
TagID  value
21     0
10     10
```

Comment: The case _expression_'s different return values should have compatible data types. Don't mix char and int.

Comment: I agree it's a bad idea to return a string in one case and a number in another. The calling code (if this is called from an application or report, or something) could get confused or even crash. Provide a consistent interface with consistent data types.

Comment: Can you please elaborate if you dont mind. i am learning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is most likely some implicit casting happening here.  The best fix is to just make sure that all branches of your `CASE` expression have the same type.  Given that the `THEN` condition is empty string, you should make all branches text:

```
SELECT
    TagID,
    CASE WHEN TagID > 10 THEN '' ELSE CAST(TagID AS varchar(max)) END AS value
FROM [dbo].tblUse;
```